# React & Enzyme: why isn't beforeEach() working?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing my first React tests and running into an issue where my `beforeEach` statement isn't working. Here's my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import IntroText from '../components/IntroText';
import Form from '../components/Form';

describe('<Home />', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
  });

  it('renders the IntroText component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(IntroText).length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('renders the Form component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(Form).length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Here's the relevant part of my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "^18.0.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
  "jest": "^18.1.0",
  "react-scripts": "0.9.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.2"
 },
"dependencies": {
  "enzyme": "^2.7.1",
  "jest-enzyme": "^2.1.2",
  "react": "^15.4.2",
  "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
  "react-router": "^3.0.2"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

I get this error when the tests run:

```
ReferenceError: wrapper is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are defining the wrapper const inside of the `beforeEach` scope, move it outside like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import IntroText from '../components/IntroText';
import Form from '../components/Form';

describe('<Home />', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
  });

  it('renders the IntroText component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(IntroText).length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('renders the Form component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(Form).length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

This way you'll have access to wrapper inside of the `it`s scope.

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let
>   statement. The value of a constant cannot change through
>   re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.

Since you want to assign the variable inside of the `beforeEach` scope and use it inside of the `it` scopes, you'll have to declare the variable in a common scope, which, in this case is the `describe` scope.

**Added (works on mocha but not on jest):**

Another possible way to fix this is to use the `this` keyword (which I prefer, if using mocha... Does not work with jest).

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import IntroText from '../components/IntroText';
import Form from '../components/Form';

describe('<Home />', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
  });

  it('renders the IntroText component', function() {
    expect(this.wrapper.find(IntroText).length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('renders the Form component', function() {
    expect(this.wrapper.find(Form).length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: This is a classic example of scope!

Comment: **If You're Still Getting Undefined**:-
I tried this ^ approach on an object i needed in my tests (it was defined in beforeEach() & then referenced/used in the test statements but STILL got undefined. Even with `this.myobject` approach ^^ .  I read the Jest docs and it looks as though they define the object itself in the global/top-level scope just below imports, *then* specify what it is in the `beforeEach()` and *then* it's fine to be used in the test statements.